# Using same column name in WHERE statement utilizing "AND" instead of "OR"

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the where statement utilizing the implodes to be an and, for whatever reason i am not able to.  the b.id_value is has multiple values that i must leverage in order to return a result.

They need to be explicit not an or statement.  any ideas?  It is being pulled from mysql and i am using php. I block quoted the part i believe i am having issues with. thanks in advance

```
$strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT a.id, uu.upload_path, b.id_user, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a.date_registration) as date_registration, e.id_user as session 
FROM ".USERS_TABLE." a 
JOIN resdescr_spr_user b ON a.id=b.id_user
LEFT JOIN ".USER_UPLOAD_TABLE." uu ON uu.id=a.icon_path 
LEFT JOIN ".ACTIVE_SESSIONS_TABLE." e ON a.id=e.id_user 
WHERE 
    a.id IN (".$in_str.") 
    AND (a.id_city IN (".$excludes.") OR a.id_city='$zipcode') 
    AND a.id IN (".implode(', ', $ids).") 
    AND (b.id_value IN (".implode(', ', $idf).") AND b.id_value IN (".implode(', ', $idc).") AND b.id_value IN (".implode(', ', $idd)."))
    AND NOT a.id='$enemy'";

$rs = $dbconn->Execute($strSQL);
```

Comment: What is the sql it produces and what's the db error?

Comment: it doesn't give an error, it just doesn't provide results based on the combined and's

Comment: Your query will search for a record with a `b.id_value` that is present in all of `$idf`, `$idc`, and `$idd`.  Is that what you want?  If you instead want to find records in `USERS_TABLE` that are related to three different `id_value`s, found in the three vars, you will have to join `resdescr_spr_user` three times as well.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you misunderstood the meaning of `AND` for `IN`-conditions. You correctly use brackets for that 3 conditions. But you probably should use `OR`

```
$strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT a.id, uu.upload_path, b.id_user, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a.date_registration) as date_registration, e.id_user as session 
FROM ".USERS_TABLE." a 
JOIN resdescr_spr_user b ON a.id=b.id_user
LEFT JOIN ".USER_UPLOAD_TABLE." uu ON uu.id=a.icon_path 
LEFT JOIN ".ACTIVE_SESSIONS_TABLE." e ON a.id=e.id_user 
WHERE 
    a.id IN (".$in_str.") 
    AND (a.id_city IN (".$excludes.") OR a.id_city='$zipcode') 
    AND a.id IN (".implode(', ', $ids).") 
    AND (b.id_value IN (".implode(', ', $idf).") OR b.id_value IN (".implode(', ', $idc).") OR b.id_value IN (".implode(', ', $idd)."))
    AND a.id != '$enemy'";

$rs = $dbconn->Execute($strSQL);
```